# keep timezone "CET" from convert into "CEST" in python

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, timestamp, pytz

If I use the following command to localize my timestamp to "CET":

```
pd.Timestamp('2011-11-06 11:00:00').tz_localize('CET')
```

output:  `Timestamp('2011-11-06 11:00:00+0100', tz='CET')`

if I use :

```
pd.Timestamp('2011-06-06 11:00:00').tz_localize('CET')
```

output: `Timestamp('2011-06-06 11:00:00+0200', tz='CET')`

So obviously it automatically convert into "CEST" in summer, am I right? what if I would like to keep my timestamp in "CET" through out the whole year (keep it UTC +1:00 all the time), what should I do? Thank you very much!

Updated:

the following seems working:

```
pd.Timestamp('2011-06-06 11:00:00').tz_localize(tz=pytz.FixedOffset(60))
```

output:`Timestamp('2011-06-06 11:00:00+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')`

any other suggestions?

Comment: I think your suggestion of using `FixedOffset` is a good one if you want this. As it the definition of the CET timezone to be different in summer and winter, so you cannot get this as such.

Comment: @joris: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any knowledge of trading hours of Eurex? the website only says they are using CET timezone, didn't mention a word about convert timezone to CET into CEST in summer. so I assume they are usiong UTC +1:00 throughout the year, am I right?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge on Eurex, but you should certainly check that by looking at some data from them in summer if this is the case. As I would expect they *do* use CEST in summer (that is normal practice when saying that it is timezone CET)